# How create seperate mobile and desktop inbox like facebook?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

When in desktop i want to show the conversation lists on left and conversation on right. And when on mobile browser the two pages should be seperate just like facebook. Is there a responsive way to do that or I have to code a different html,css file for that ?
I am using mean stack with jquery and bootstrap .

I havent been able to find an example of this kind chat on web. The ones i see, the conversations go below when the window is made small , so any links would be very useful

Comment: media queries? show/hide?

Comment: Can you give me any example link.  I couldn't find any in google .

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: Do you know about the bootstrap classes `visible-xs` , `hidden-xs` , etc. ?

Comment: Is those for v4 alpha ?

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.